# SSIS Error : Non-SysAdmins have been denied permission

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am running this SSIS Package but I am getting this error

```
Non-SysAdmins have been denied permission to run DTS Execution job steps without a proxy account.  The step failed.
```

There are many other packages that are working fine but this one I get an error

I wonder if anyone have faced this error and fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution

The problem is that "`Run as`" in the Job step Property was empty

[image]

changed that to `BI_SSISProxy/Account`
now it is working

Comment: What if that `Run as` dropdown is empty?

Comment: @mmcrae make sure to have SQL Server Integration Service Package in the "Type" dropdown